# Allocate an array of uninitalized user defined types in the stack

Tags: c++, memory, containers

I have a class that acts as a container (class Graph) of a fixed capacity, and I have a class that has no default constructor, that will be the elements of this container (class Node).

I want the Graph to create Nodes, giving me back a reference of the Node it just created.

With a `std::vector<Node>` this is trivial using `reserve` and `push_back`. However, I would prefer avoiding using the heap if possible.

I tried with a `std::array` but my understanding is that elements in the array must be initialized. But this is not possible because elements are not default constructable.

What can I do to get something like vector's `reserve` but in the static/stack memory?

Comment: Get a static allocator and use a vector with that allocator.

Comment: @NathanOliver is there any static allocator in the std or should I write/import one?

Comment: There isn't one baked into the standard library but there should be plenty of them out there that you can copy and use.  Boost even has a `static_vector` class if you don't mind a boost dependency.

Comment: Wouldn't just pmr work? https://godbolt.org/z/Wevfado1a

Comment: @alagner I guess that would work, but I think that is just too complex. What I want to achieve in practice is to change the sizeof Graph from sizeof(Graph) to `sizeof(Graph) + sizeof(Nodes)*fixedAmount`, and then have access to that extra space.

Answer (score 2):

When you want a std::array with std::vector semantics, what you want is [std::static_vector](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0843r2.html) or [fixed_capacity_vector](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0843r0.html) or (newest proposal) [inplace_vector](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p0843r8.html).

Unfortunately it hasn't worked its way all the way through standardization yet.

There are a few implementations out there, such as the one in [gnzblg's github](https://github.com/gnzlbg/static_vector), [boosts](https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost/container/static_vector.html), [EASTLs's fixed_vector](https://github.com/questor/eastl/blob/master/fixed_vector.h#L71) or [folly's small_vector](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/main/folly/docs/small_vector.md). Some of these have a "fallback" where if you exceed the preallocated size, they revert to normal `vector` behavior.

Comment: I see these solutions as valid, but maybe I'm overshooting. What I'm trying to achieve is something like `Node nodes[fixedSize]`, but only increasing the stack size, without calling constructors (destructors are fine though). I don't need any fancy functionality on top of that.

Comment: @lilezek This is pretty much exactly what the static_vector implementations are for. The objects aren't created until you push_back or emplace_back, but the space is allocated (plus a small size count). There are some object lifetime complications if you try to make it simpler than this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a buffer of raw memory sufficient to store enough of your objects, including alignment.

Inplace construct objects in the raw memory buffer as you need them.  Keep track of which objects exist.

Using std span and std launder, provide access to the range of valid objects on request.

C++ has some standardization issues with treating arrays of individually constructed objects as an array of that object, but the actual implementations of C++ do not.  (I am not certain if C++23 fully solved these issues).

Alternatively, find a static vector implementation and use it.